Sprayer for soft washing my vinyl siding
I clean my vinyl siding by spraying a bleach solution through a garden sprayer and washing off with a hose afterwards. My house is small but I still have to get up on a ladder to reach some areas, and it takes a half a day to do. This year, to save time I am looking for some kind of pump sprayer or injector hose attachment that has more range than the garden sprayer.
Ideally, I'm looking for a garden hose attachment that has the same range as a typical spray handle but also allows for adjustable chemical injection so I can dial in the bleach solution I want.
I used to pressure wash in the past, without any chemical injection. While this worked, I feel it is too harsh for my siding. Really, my concern is that I'm not sure how the vinyl siding was installed. My house doesn't have OSB or plywood sheathing, it has some type of fiber board sheathing that doesn't really hold nails. Also, my house originally had asbestos shingle. I'm not sure if the siders removed the asbestos, wrapped the sheathing in Tyvek and nailed the vinyl to the studs, or if they installed the Tyvek and vinyl over top the asbestos but still managed to find the studs, or if they used some way of mounting the vinyl directly to the asbestos that I'm not familiar with. Whatever was done was done before I owned the house. I'm not saying the siders did a bad job. In fact the opposite is true - the vinyl has held up really well. I'm just saying I don't know how they did it. I guess I can probe a little and find out.
Anyway, recommendations please and thank you.

I use a 5 gallon bucket filled with a bleach solution and a soft bristle deck brush attached to a telescoping pole. I rinse with the garden hose. No worries about wind conditions or overspray. And no ladder.
You could, with the right fittings, a telescoping pole, some tubing, and tape, make your own sprayer extension pretty easily.
